# XMLHttpRequest Status returns 0

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I know this question has been answered several times on SO itself. However, I was looking for more clarification with my particular example. I was hoping someone could please further explain the reason why this is happening with the following code.

```
<script>
    function get (url, callback) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "file:///C:/Circles/demos/data1.json");
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            alert(request.status);
            if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
                var type = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                if (type === "application/json") {
                    callback(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
                }
                else callback(request.responseText);
            }
        };
        request.send(null);
    }
    get();
</script>
```

I get the readyState as 4, but the status is 0. I'm trying this on Google Chrome. I want to try and parse the JSON file.

Please note I'm trying to parse a local JSON file. Any pointers on how to parse a local JSON file would be appreciated.

Comment: you can't use "file://". it needs to be on a web server

Comment: I had a feeling I was doing it wrongly. How do you suggest I parse a local JSON file in JavaScript? Not the jQuery.parseJSON method.

Comment: install some free LAMP envoirement.-L .. Apache php mysql..

Comment: Yes, localhost seems a viable option. Can I not parse this programatically via JS, using someother methodology? I don't want to install another tool, as there are certain constraints.

Comment: @AbhishekSha: you can use a <input type=file> to get data from local files.